# Certification of Declaration meaning

Tags: phrase-request, formal-language

I should create an official document in English saying that the mentioned employee underwent Internship in our Institute/Department from 1.1.2014 to 31.12.2014.

After the line "To whom it may concern" I want to place a header like

"Certification of Declaration"
"Confirmation letter"
"Verification" etc...

I chose "Certification of Declaration", however I am not sure it is appropriate header to use.

My questions are:

1. What "Certification of Declaration" means exactly and if it can be used in the mentioned context? (I did not find an explanation in Google).
2. Could you please suggest a proper if C-o-D is not appropriate.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context *certification* and *declaration* mean very similar things: they both claim to be an authoritative statement of something. That makes *"certification of declaration"* confusing: it would imply that you certify that you declare that you have declared something.

I think you should go for **Letter of Confirmation**. It has the spirit of your original, but is much more natural English: it is a letter and the purpose of the letter is to confirm. (Other letters might be letters of denunciation, of concern, of approval; this is one of confirmation).

Comment: Agree. Another possibility, more specific, would be "Confirmation of Internship" (but **not** _Letter of Confirmation of Internship_ —that would be too much!)